# How to evaluate multiple time series forcasting model?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, rms

Hi I have multiple time series forcasting model and I want to evaluate the predictive power of this model. Let's say, we are predicting $A_T$ and $B_T$ by using $A_t,t\in[0,...,T-1]$ and $B_t,t\in[0,...,T-1]$

I found Normalized Root Mean Square (NRMS) and Root Mean Square (RMS) are very common measures for evaluation of time series forcasting model, but how to generalize it for multiple time series forcasting?

Answer (score 1):

Relatedly for regression with multi-dependent variables, [per a source](https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-models-with-multiple-target-variables-8baa75aacd):

> ...the default metric used is the relative error, which is
> the mean squared error of predictions divided by the mean squared error of a default hypothesis always predicting the mean.

which provides a general frame leading to a metric. Note, this relates to one of your mentioned metrics, to quote [a reference](https://agrimetsoft.com/calculators/Normalized%20Root%20Mean%20Square%20Error):

> The Normalized Root Mean Square Error (NRMSE)
>
> the RMSE facilitates the comparison between models with different scales. the normalised RMSE (NRMSE) which relates the RMSE to the observed range of the variable. Thus, the NRMSE can be interpreted as a fraction of the overall range that is typically resolved.